# Probability problem with markov property

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Problem: In a test paper, the questions are arranged so that 3/4's of the time a True is followed by a True and 2/3's of the time a False is followed by a False. You are confronted with a 100 questions text. Approximately what fraction of the answers will be true? [assume markov property]

Attempt: $p_T=p_T\times p_{T,T}+P_F\times p_{F,T}=p_T\times \frac{3}{4}+p_F\times \frac{1}{3}$, thus we have : $p_T=(1-p_T)\frac{1}{3}$, which implies $p_T=\frac{4}{7}$. Thus the required fraction is $\frac{4}{7}$. Is my solution right? If it is, then what is the significance of the phrase "100 questions text" in the problem?

Remark: In my solution, "T" stands for True and "F" stands for false.

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: I think you touched a nerve with the second question. The problem really only gives you a probability matrix whose entries are the probabilities to move from T to T, T to F, F to T and F to T.

Comment: I did not quite get you, sorry, is my solution correct?

Comment: Basically you are saying that you know (can compute) the probability of an answer to be true or false even though the problem appears to require (at least) 100 questions to get an idea what that could be. The given probabilities look like transition probabilities.

Comment: Okay, so how do you do this problem?

Comment: you are right after all, it is $4/7$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_n$ be the probability of the $n$-th answer to be true, $n\geq 1$. Using the Markov property we have for all $n\geq 2$:
$$p_n = p_{n-1}\cdot (1-1/4) + (1-p_{n-1})\cdot 1/3.   $$
Let $s = \frac{1/3}{1/3+1/4}$ and note that $s=s\cdot (1-1/4)+(1-s)\cdot 1/3$. Then we get:
$$p_n-s = (p_{n-1}-s)(1-1/3-1/4).$$
So, after taking absolute value on both sides and iterating:
$$|p_n - s| = |p_1-s||1-1/3-1/4|^{n-1}.$$
For large $n$, noting that $|1-1/3-1/4|<1$, $p_n$ approaches fast $s$.